# Windows Phone 8 and read/write file

Tags: c#, c++, windows-phone-8

My application have a small piece of code which read/write a file in C++/CX (Windows Phone 8 Interop DirectX) like this:

```
bool WriteState(char *fileName) {
    FILE *fp = fopen(fileName);
    if (fp) {
        // Do save
        ...
        fclose(fp);
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

and `ReadState` has the same code. and invoking (call from C#):

```
ObjectClass game = new ObjectClass();
game.WriteState("game1.state");
```

It's no problem when I run on my device, debug with no error. But after I published to Windows Phone Store and install to my device, the `Read/Write` code doesn't work. Why this happen?

Comment: Where are you saving the file? Your app won't have access to its install location in production. You'll need to save in isolated storage.

Comment: @RobCaplan: Thanks you, I got it, resolved, please make your comment as an answer so I can accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you aren't saving the file in its install location. Your app won't have access to its install location in production. You'll need to save in isolated storage.

Answer (score 3):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj681698(v=vs.105).aspx

There is this way, that should work for you..

Comment: The reason is my app doen't have permission to access its install location.